# Can't override server port in jenkins

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins-plugins

in windows batch command

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--server.port=8085
```

doesn't work

the console outputs:

```
main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8085 (https) with context path ''
2019-05-20 14:05:45.622  INFO 3144 --- [           main] g.s.i.InternalPortalApplication          : Started InternalPortalApplication in 14.031 seconds (JVM running for 28.877)
```

Comment: Showing 8085 port in your command and console output as well. What you want as expected output?

Comment: the website doesn't started

Comment: whats the url you trying to access? what error are you receiving in logs?